# Send message to Telegram bot Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

I have such code, that can send message to user, but how can I implement sending message to bot and read it? I have to see what user send to bot.

Code:

```
import telegram

api_key = 'mytoken'
user_id = 'myID'

bot = telegram.Bot(token='mytoken')

bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text='How r u doing?')
```